# C# importing class into another class doesn't work

Tags: c#, class, program-entry-point

I'm quite new to C#, and have made a class that I would like to use in my main class. These two classes are in different files, but when I try to import one into the other with `using`, cmd says says

> The type or namespace name "MyClass" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

I know that in Java I have to mess around with `CLASSPATH` to get things like this to work, but I have no idea about C#.

Additional details:

As you've probably figured out, I'm compiling and executing via command prompt. I'm compiling my non-main class using `/target:library` (I heard that only main classes should be .exe-files).

My code looks like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    void stuff() {

    }
}
```

and my main class:

```
using System;
using MyClass;

public class MyMainClass {
    static void Main() {
        MyClass test = new MyClass();
        /* Doesn't work */
    }
}
```

I have tried to encompass my non-main class with `namespace MyNamespace { }` and importing that, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: You do pass the generated library as an input to the compiler when you compile the main class, right? Also, you should be able to pass both source files together to the compiler - no need for a library here.

Comment: Have you added the other file (the one where `MyClass` is in) to the solution in Visual studio?

Comment: @JensKloster What solution? What visual studio? I'm not using an IDE, I'm using command prompt.

Comment: @Alex How do I do that? :o

Comment: Why do you compile from the command line? The first class is compiled into a DLL-file. When you compile the second assembly (with `MyMainClass`) you will have to reference the first assembly. If you're using C# Project files (`*.csproj`) from Visual Studio, right click on "References", "Add Reference...", and point to the DLL from your first compilation. If you don't use `csproj`-files, use [/r compiler option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yabyz3h4.aspx).

Comment: @Bluefire I've edited my answer with detailed explanation how to do that.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**UPDATE**: As of C# 6, if you want to use the **static members of a class** without specifying the class name, you can use the [using static directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) to import the static members into the current scope, like this:

```
using static MyNamespace.MyClass;
```

Although this is not what the original question is about, you get a similar error to the one OP gets, so I'm providing it for completeness.

**Answer to OP's question**:

`using` is for namespaces only - if both classes are in the same namespace just drop the `using`.

You have to reference the assembly created in the first step when you compile the .exe:

```
csc /t:library /out:MyClass.dll MyClass.cs
csc /reference:MyClass.dll /t:exe /out:MyProgram.exe MyMainClass.cs
```

You can make things simpler if you just compile the files together:

```
csc /t:exe /out:MyProgram.exe MyMainClass.cs MyClass.cs
```

or

```
csc /t:exe /out:MyProgram.exe *.cs
```

**EDIT**:
Here's how the files should look like:

**MyClass.cs**:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    public class MyClass {
        void stuff() {
 
        }
    }
}
```

**MyMainClass.cs**:

```
using System;

namespace MyNamespace {
    public class MyMainClass {
        static void Main() {
            MyClass test = new MyClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But when I do have them both in the same namespace, it gives me exactly the same error when I try to use it.

Comment: @Bluefire Post the command line that you use to compile them and the content of the files, including the namespaces.

Comment: Best answer since it actually gives the command lines for compiling. Original Poster will have to decide if he wants the classes in two separate assemblies (compile one class to library (DLL), then compile second class to executable with reference to DLL of first compilation) or in just one assembly (compile once with both files). This is something many people manage by having "projects" inside Visual Studio where the projects reference each other (in a non-circular way) and each project can containg one or more code files.

Answer (score 31):

I know this is very old question but I had the same requirement and just discovered that after c#6 you can use static in using for classes to import.

I hope this helps someone....

```
using static yourNameSpace.YourClass;
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer if you want to have implicit imports of all public fields from yourNameSpace.YourClass. This was my need.

Answer (score 7):

Well what you have to "import" (use) the namespace of `MyClass` not the class name itself. If both classes are in the same namespace, you don't have to "import" it.

Definition `MyClass.cs`

```
namespace Ns1
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Usage `AnotherClass.cs`

```
using Ns1;

namespace AnotherNs
{
    public class AnotherClass
    {
        public AnotherClass()
        {
            var myInst = new MyClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If they are separate class files within the same project, then you do not need to have an 'import' statement.  Just use the class straight off.  If the files are in separate projects, you need to add a reference to the project first before you can use an 'import' statement on it.

Answer (score 2):

If the other class is compiled as a library (i.e. a dll) and this is how you want it, you should add a reference from visual studio, browse and point to to the dll file.

If what you want is to incorporate the OtherClassFile.cs into your project, and the namespace is already identical, you can:

1. Close your solution,
2. Open  **YourProjectName.csproj** file, and look for this section:

   ```
   <ItemGroup>                                            
       <Compile Include="ExistingClass1.cs" />                     
       <Compile Include="ExistingClass2.cs" />                                 
       ...
       <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />     
   </ItemGroup>
   ```

1. Check that the .cs file that you want to add is in the project folder (same folder as all the existing classes in the solution).
2. Add an entry inside as below, save and open the project.

   ```
   <Compile Include="OtherClassFile.cs" />
   ```

Your class, will now appear and behave as part of the project. No using is needed. This can be done multiple files in one shot.

Comment: I had the same issue, and Added the new class to the solution to the right in VS, but it wasn't showing the same as other classes.  I opened the csproj like he says and it didn't look unusual.  I re-opened my VS project, and it looked normal to the right in the project like the other classes.  Now it's being recognized by my project.

Answer (score 1):

`MyClass` is a **class** not a **namespace**. So this code is wrong:

```
using MyClass //THIS CODE IS NOT CORRECT
```

You should check the namespace of the `MyClass` (e.g: MyNamespace). Then call it in a proper way:

```
MyNamespace.MyClass myClass =new MyNamespace.MyClass();
```

Answer (score 1):

`using` is used for importing namespaces not classes.

So if your class is in namespace `X`

```
namespace X
{
    public class MyClass {
         void stuff() {

         }
    }
}
```

then to use it in another namespace where you want it

```
using System;
using X;

public class MyMainClass {
    static void Main() {
        MyClass test = new MyClass();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyMainClass
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            MyClass test = new MyClass();
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        void Stuff()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

You have no need for using a namespace then because it is all encompased in the same namespace.

If you are unsure of what namespace your class is located, type the class (case sensitive you wish to use) then with your cursor on the class, use `CTRL` + `.` and it will offer you a manual import.